# "Humans turn" or "Humans' turn"?

Tags: possessives

In a game where there are two factions fighting each other and they take turns moving their units, if I want to inform the player of the game which faction's turn it is, should I use a possessive noun?

Eg. in this specific case, I have a game where Humans fight Monsters. **Should I say *Humans Turn* or *Humans' Turn*?**

I can't say why but I feel like the former is correct. I don't recall any video game having a message like *Player 1's Turn*, just *Player 1 Turn* but the more I think about it the more the possessive form makes sense.

Or maybe it should actually be *Human turn*?

Comment: 'Humans Turn' is saying that there is a bunch of humans, and they do indeed turn to face a different direction. I suspect this is not what you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Humans' turn** is correct. Your plural form already ends with an 's', so you form a possessive by adding an apostrophe.

Comment: So, a possessive is needed because the turn "belongs" to humans? Or is there some other kind of relationship between nouns that can warrant using a possessive?

Comment: In ordinary English, you would certainly use a possessive form for this: _my turn_, _your turn_, _his turn_, _David's turn_, _white's turn'; so _Humans' turn_. What you would say in game-maker's-instruction-language might be different (especially if the game was made by people who did not have English as their first language).

Comment: Heh, I didn't think about "my turn". I guess if we were not supposed to use a possessive we'd need to say "I turn" for it to make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now it's the Humans' turn. Down with the Monsters!